# it's possible to use Java.awt.Image android application

Tags: java, android, image, graphics, awt

I've written a Java methods ,but i have to use this method in android project,so someone can help me to convert it into android or help me what should i do?

```
public Image getImage(){

    ColorModel cm = grayColorModel() ;

    if( n == 1){// in case it's a  8 bit/pixel image 
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new MemoryImageSource(w, h,cm, pixData, 0, w));

    }//endif

}

   protected  ColorModel grayColorModel()
   {
    byte[] r = new byte[256] ;
    for (int i = 0; i <256 ; i++ )
        r[i] = (byte)(i & 0xff ) ;
return (new IndexColorModel(8,256,r,r,r));
}
```

Comment: Please share more info, what's your input value ? what's specification of pixData ? what do you want in output ?

Comment: pixData[] : a vector contains image pixels from a dicom file,
i want to convert this vector of pixels into image

Comment: pixData is grayscale image ?

Comment: pixData is a vector of bytes (byte[]  pixData;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, to convert a grayscale image (byte array, imageSrc) to drawable:

```
        byte[] imageSrc= [...];
        // That's where the RGBA array goes.
        byte[] imageRGBA = new byte[imageSrc.length * 4];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < imageSrc.length; i++) {
            imageRGBA[i * 4] = imageRGBA[i * 4 + 1] = imageRGBA[i * 4 + 2] = ((byte) ~imageSrc[i]);

            // Invert the source bits
            imageRGBA[i * 4 + 3] = -1;// 0xff, that's the alpha.
        }

        // Now put these nice RGBA pixels into a Bitmap object
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(imageRGBA));
```

Code may differ depending of input format.

Comment: thanks a lot my  friend ,your code  code works correctly 
really i appreciate your help

Comment: when i use  a large vector in my input value (imageSrc)
it makes exception (android out of memory on  a 66073612 byte allocation ) what should i do?

Comment: @Houssem, your image is too big 66MB. Please have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#RestrictingMemory, https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory, https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: i've just had a look at the articles .i think that i should add "Options" to my code but how can i use this: 
bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.imageName, opts);

Comment: I think best way is to reduce original image. Because show an image on Android device with a size of 66MB is unnecessary.

Comment: the size of the original image is 15 mb

Comment: You're right but it's in grayscale format, android can't display image in grayscale format. I think your grayscale format is 1 pixel = 1 byte. In android 1pixel (RGB) = 4 byte.  That's why, there's a "new byte[imageSrc.length * 4]" in code. Size is multiplied by 4 (15x4=60).

Comment: Thanks dear i understand that,you want to say there is no solution for this code no?

Comment: You could rescale original image, for instance: http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/ or http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/bilinear-image-scaling/ (with function "resizeBilinearGray")

Comment: i increase the heap size of the application by android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest.xml and it works

Comment: Good news, but be careful heap value differ depending device's model. If you use always same device's model, no problem.